# Node.js/Express request.session undefined?

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have a node/socket/express site that has been up for several months, and all-of-a-sudden I'm getting errors when simply trying to load the home page. This is my server.js file:

```
var bugsnag = require("bugsnag");
bugsnag.register(KEY);
var Lobby = require('./lobby').Lobby
var express = require('express')
var engine = require('ejs-locals')
var app = express()
  , cookieParser = express.cookieParser('secret')
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , cookie  =   require('cookie')
  , connect =   require('connect')
  , MemoryStore = connect.middleware.session.MemoryStore
  , sessionStore
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(bugsnag.requestHandler);
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(express.session({secret:'secret',key:'express.sid',store:sessionStore = new MemoryStore(),maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000}));
app.use(bugsnag.errorHandler);

io.set('authorization', function (handshake, accept) {
  if (!handshake.headers.cookie) 
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
  handshake.cookie = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie);
  cookieParser(handshake, {}, function(err) {
    if(handshake.signedCookies){
      handshake.sessionID = handshake.signedCookies['express.sid'];
      sessionStore.load(handshake.sessionID, function (err, session) {
        if (err)
          accept(err.message, false); //Turn down the connection
        else {
          handshake.session = session; //Accept the session
          accept(null, true);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbConnection;
app.configure('development', function(){
  dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({DEV_CONNECTION_STRING});
  io.set('log level', 3);
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({PROD_CONNECTION_STRING});
  io.set('log level', 0);
});
dbConnection.connect(function(error){if(error){return console.log("CONNECTION error: "+error);}});

//var domain = require('domain');
app.engine('ejs', engine); // use ejs-locals for all ejs templates:
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // so you can render('index')

var lobbya = new Lobby(io,dbConnection,'lobbya');
var lobbyz = new Lobby(io,dbConnection,'lobbyz');

server.listen(8080); //4000

require('./routes').addRoutes(app,dbConnection);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {clientConnect(socket)});

function clientConnect(socket) {
  var session = socket.handshake.session;
  if (session == null) {
    socket.emit('sign out');
    dbConnection.query("Insert into eventlog (type, details) values ('boot no session','"+JSON.stringify(session)+"');");    
  }
  else if (session.player == null) {
    socket.emit('sign out');
    dbConnection.query("Insert into eventlog (type, details) values ('boot no player','"+JSON.stringify(session)+"');");
  }
  else {
    socket.on('join room', function (room) {
      dbConnection.query("Insert into eventlog (type, details) values ('join room','"+room+":"+JSON.stringify(session)+"');");
      if (room == 'lobbya')
        lobbya.connect('',socket,session.player);
      else if (room == 'lobbyz')
        lobbyz.connect('',socket,session.player);
      else if (room.substring(0,5) == 'gamea') //join game, figure out which game
        lobbya.gameConnect('',socket,session.player,room.substring(5,room.length),sessionStore);
      else if (room.substring(0,5) == 'gamez') //join game, figure out which game
        lobbyz.gameConnect('',socket,session.player,room.substring(5,room.length),sessionStore); 
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the top of my routes file where the error is happening:

```
var Simulator = require('./simulator').Simulator;
var email = require("emailjs/email");
var url = require('url');

exports.addRoutes = function(app, dbConnection) {
  app.get('/', function(request,response){
    dbConnection.query("SELECT sum(games_finished) as games, max(longest_win_streak) as streak, max(games_won) as wins FROM players;",
    function (error, results, fields) {
      var games = Math.ceil(results[0]['games']/2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      var streak = results[0]['streak'].toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      var wins = results[0]['wins'].toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      dbConnection.query("SELECT p1.username as user1, p2.username as user2, gl.player1_score, gl.player2_score, DATE_FORMAT(gl.created_at - INTERVAL 8 hour, '%b %e %l:%i %p') as created_at FROM gamelog gl join players p1 on gl.player1_id = p1.id join players p2 on gl.player2_id = p2.id where gl.end_type = 'pegout' ORDER BY gl.created_at DESC limit 3;",
       function (error, results, fields) { 
        latestResults = [];
        for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
          if (results[i]['player1_score'] > results[i]['player2_score'])
        latestResults[i] = results[i]['created_at'] + ' - ' + results[i]['user1']+' def. '+results[i]['user2']+' 121-'+results[i]['player2_score'];
          else
            latestResults[i] = results[i]['created_at'] + ' - ' + results[i]['user2']+' def. '+results[i]['user1']+' 121-'+results[i]['player1_score'];
        }
        response.render('index', { player: request.session.player , error: '', room: '', games: games, streak: streak, wins: wins, latestResults: latestResults });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

The error is happening when rendering the "index" ejs, and the error is related to request.session.player. Specifically, "can't read property 'player' of undefined"

I don't understand how the session can be undefined? This isn't happening for me locally. Is it perhaps because it's rejecting the handshake in the io.set('authorization') part of the code? If so, what's the right thing to do if that handshake is rejected in that part of the code?

Comment: I bet if you clear your cookies or open in an incognito window you will see the error locally.

Comment: Good thoughts pllee, but both work just fine. I'll see what happens if I disable cookies entirely (rather than just clearing them)